# How to send sms using https url from 3rd party sms provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

[I used this link] (https://ozeki-sms-gateway.com/p_677-how-to-send-sms-from-c-sharp-using-http-get.html)

This code did not work.

The link given from the company had senderID, which is not exist the given oziki url.

Comment: What did you see, which makes you think it didn't work?

Comment: I did not recieve any meesage. However, when I put the string in the browser, I recieved a message. Even, because the method OnPost, I did not recieve the cobsole messages mentioned.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The same code works fine.
The server shows a sending request for the sms http correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by asker’s machine?

Comment: Ah, you answered your own question, sorry.